# How is the array syntax supposed to work with Angular's $routeParams service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning JavaScript. In the course, there is following task:

> Inject the routeParams service into the NotesShowController so that we get access to the id in the URL.

I wrote this code:

```
angular.module('NoteWrangler')
.controller('NotesShowController', [function($http, $routeParams) {
  var controller = this;
  $http({method:'GET', url:'/notes/' + $routeParams.id})
  .success(function(data){
    controller.note = data;
  });
}]);
```

But I get the error - the teaching system says

> Make sure that you're injecting the $routeParams service correctly with the array syntax.

What's wrong with my `$routeParams` injection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update

```
.controller('NotesShowController', [function($http, $routeParams) {
```

to

```
.controller('NotesShowController', ['$http', '$routeParams', function($http, $routeParams) {
```